# Python: Insert an object into .xlsx file

Tags: python, xlsx, openpyxl, xlsxwriter, xlwings

I'm using Python 3.5 and xlsxwriter to create reports in excel, These reports require to have outlook .msg files embedded in the excel rows (which is usually done by adding them as "objects" in excel, just like you would do with a .pdf file for example)

example of object in excel:

[image]

Unfortunately xlsxwriter seems to have methods for inserting images (worksheet.insert_image), buttons (worksheet.insert_button) and charts but no objects. I tried using insert_image with the .msg file but it gave an error.

```
   worksheet.insert_image(row, col + 6,'C:/object1.msg')
```

Error: "Exception: C:/object1.msg: Unknown or unsupported image file format.

My question is, is there any library or xlsxwriter method to insert an object (.pdf or .msg file or whatever) into an xlsx file?

Comment: can you provide a piece of code that shows what you are trying so far?

Comment: That isn’t possible with/supported by XlsxWriter. You could probably do it with one of the non-Linux modules that support automation such as xlwings.